# Restart to repair Drive errors

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, ssd

For a few months now I keep being bugged by Windows about restarting my PC to repair errors the most annoying thing is that even if I restart nothing happens(didn't try this with the SSD yet) I even tried running `Chkdsk` by hand with no success.

I've changed 2 HDDs by now (didn't trow them away just turned them into external HDDs), but every time I do it seams ok for a week or two after which I get the message again.

I've bought a new SSD(for about 3 weeks) and yesterday I started getting the message again even though the utilities for it say that everything is ok.

My laptop is a [Toshiba Sattelite](http://www.toshiba.eu/discontinued-products/satellite-l505-13t/) and I'm running Windows 8.1

What's wrong with it ? Should I be worried that something on this laptop is damaging my drives ?

Comment: It could be a bad hard drive to motherboard cable, or a failing motherboard.

Comment: @Moab anyway I can check this ? A tool maybe or something ?

Comment: No, replace the cable to see if it solves it, not much you can do if it is the motherboard. Outside possibility it could be a memory module is flaky, [test the memory using this software.](http://www.memtest.org/)

Comment: What was the exact message you were getting? Were there any entries in your event log that pointed to problems?

Comment: Yes, dig through the Event logs in Window to see if they say anything related. eventvwr.msc > Windows Logs  > System probably.